# Updating an ActiveX wrapper in vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, activex

I’m sure this is a simple question for somebody. We have a few legacy C++ projects that still use our own ActiveX controls. In vs6 it was pretty simple to update the auto-gen’d wrapper when those controls changed, you simple re-inserted the control, VS recognised that the control was already in the project and updated the wrapper. I cannot see how to do this in vs2008, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

After a bit of phaphing I’ll answer my own question. In the end I re-installed VS6, created a new test app and re-inserted the ActiveX control. I then diff’d over the changes to my vs2008 project. It worked but it really shouldn’t be like this.
Microsoft really messed up with the MFC/AFX integration; they clearly don’t care about it anymore.